# nftables meter error: syntax error, unexpected saddr, expecting comma or '}'

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter, nftables

I have below nftable rule to add a connection rate meter:

```
nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport @rate_limit meter syn4-meter \{ ip  saddr . tcp dport timeout 5m limit rate 20/minute \} counter accept
```

It generates the error:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected saddr, expecting comma or '}'
add rule ip filter input tcp dport @rate_limit ct state new meter syn4-meter { ip saddr . tcp dport timeout 5m limit rate 20/minute } counter accept
                                                                                  ^^^^^
```

#### nftables ruleset

```
table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
table inet filter {
    set rate_limit {
        type inet_service
        size 50
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

Initially I tried just `inet` but due to the error I added `ip` to see if it make any difference to no success. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- using a too old version of nftables.

  I could reproduce the error `Error: syntax error, unexpected saddr, expecting comma or '}'` using nftables version 0.7 (as found in Debian 9). [Meters (nftables wiki)](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters) suggests *nftables* >= 0.8.1 and *kernel* >= 4.3.

  Upgrade *nftables*. Eg, on Debian 9, using the [*stretch-backports*](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) (*stretch-backports*, not *buster-backports*) version `0.9.0-1~bpo9+1`, sorry you'll have to search how to do that on other distributions.
- using the wrong table, as told by the command (when using nftables 0.9.2):

  ```
  # nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport @rate_limit meter syn4-meter \{ ip  saddr . tcp dport timeout 5m limit rate 20/minute \} counter accept
  Error: No such file or directory; did you mean set ‘rate_limit’ in table inet ‘filter’?
  ```

  Indeed, many objects are local to the table where they are declared. So you can't declare it in the *inet filter* "namespace" and use it in the *ip filter* "namespace". That's a difference with for example `iptables` + `ipset`, where the same ipset *set* can be used in any table.

  This will work (once you get a recent enough nftables):

  ```
  nft add rule inet filter input tcp dport @rate_limit meter syn4-meter \{ ip  saddr . tcp dport timeout 5m limit rate 20/minute \} counter accept
  ```

  Or alternatively you can move back the meter definition to the *ip filter* table.

Comment: Thanks @A.B I am definitely going to down loads of coffee while upgrading this bad boy -- thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though. I've installed nft from stretch-backport (v0.9.0) but I still get an error when trying to use flag `dynamic`.